# Interface Generics Overload

Tags: java, c#, kotlin

I can do the following in c#. Is it possible to do the same in kotlin or java?

```
public interface IFactory<in TModel, out TOutModel>
{
    TOutModel Create(TModel model1);
}

public interface IFactory<in TModel1, in TModel2, out TOutModel>
{
    TOutModel Create(TModel1 model1, TModel2 model2);
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't have output parameters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JVM doesn't allow overloading interfaces, classes, or methods on number of generic parameters.

A JVM-based language could allow this by giving different names to these two interfaces in bytecode, but neither Java nor Kotlin do (and I don't know of any language which does).

Comment: Note "JVM-based".

Comment: Understood. I thought this "and I don't know of any language which does" was generic.